# Is there such a thing as "public var Method()"?

Tags: c#, var, type-inference

I've done some research and found nothing so far.

```
public var Method()
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: No. Methods signatures must be explicitly typed.

Comment: Try to use public object Method(){}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. Per the specification, using the identifier `var` for implicit typing is only allowed in the context of a local variable declaration. Eric Lippert's article on [why var is not valid for fields](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx) raises a number of issues with implementing it outside the local variable context, which apply to using it in method signatures as well. Two issues are raised:

1. It significantly complicates analysis of types at the top level since many of the compiler's algorithms for overload resolution were written assuming all top level types are known.
2. The inferred type of the `var` field could be an anonymous type and there is no standard for how these types can be unified across assemblies.

As is pointed out in the article, these are not insurmountable problems but they indicate that there could be significant costs to implementing `var` outside a local variable declaration. The article was written in 2009, perhaps it is easier to implement in the Roslyn compiler.

Comment: *If* C# had `var` from the beginning it might be a different story .. but as such I find this a fair explanation of the why it's not valid, besides simply "it's disallowed by the specification".

Answer (score 14):

You can use `dynamic`.

```
public dynamic Method() {
}
```

..however, you should probably re-think your design. Your consumers of this method will *not* know what type you pass out. Therefore, you may as well split it into individual methods with expected types. The amount of logic you'll write just to make sure what you have returned out is what you expect means splitting the functions with proper types is less work.

Also, `dynamic` is not the same as `var`. `dynamic` means "anything".. `var` means "whatever is declared on the other side of this assignment". Since you can't use `var` in the context of a method return value (it isn't an assignment).. the only option is `dynamic`. When you can return "anything" out of a method, your code is very open to bugs.

**TLDR**: You're setting yourself up for a headache. Don't do it.

Comment: +1. Lambda could be close, but you can't do `var foo=(){return 42;}` either :(

Comment: ...no but I can see how that might be an interesting thing Alexei. Perhaps a pull request to Roslyn? :P

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Should it ([a lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)) be a Func<>/Action<> or an Expression<>? One would have to add new syntax or a rule for disambiguation.

Comment: I would say it should infer `Func<int>` and have, say, `expr` to separate the two..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I concur .. but that's not how C# is currently defined :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx):

> Beginning in Visual C# 3.0, variables that are declared at method
>   scope can have an implicit type var. An implicitly typed local
>   variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type
>   yourself, but the compiler determines the type. The following two declarations of i are functionally equivalent:

```
var i = 10; // implicitly typed 
int i = 10; //explicitly typed
```

If you have a function with a `public var Method()` signature, The return type is not expressed implicitly, and therefore the compiler cannot determine the type on it's on.

So, the answer to you question is: No, such a signature will not compile....

Comment: The compiler *could* determine the type (as is done in Scala), for method signatures with bodies, but the C# specification does not currently allow for such a provision. Trivially, imagine: `var Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }` (While I'm not advocating such is good, it's *not* due "[a] compiler cannot determine the type" ..)

Comment: @user2864740 In your example it is possible, but consider `Interfaces`: `var Add(int a, int b);` or `abstract var Add(int a, int b);` in those cases, the compiler cannot have a clue about the return type.